# Protect against dalvik changes in android

Tags: android, android-lvl

Is there a way to protect my app from those tools that change the dalvik cache?

I use licensing (heavily modified) and I want to protect it against "*lucky patcher tool*" found [here](http://lucky-patcher.netbew.com/).

Any idea how?
Please help
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not possible, sorry! Android LVL has been cracked, the most you can do is proguard the app and forget about making it cracker-proof and conserve the energy in looking after users of your app instead!

Comment: I dont want it to be perfect. I want to protect against specific  type of cracking which is delvik. Its not possible?!!!

Comment: Care to give more details about this specific cracking which is delvik? (Do **you** mean dalvik? as in the DalvikVM?)

Comment: I wish I understand it to give more details. Yes I mean DalvikVM. I just heard that LuckyPatcher is a way of cracking apps by changing Dalvik cache

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually researched [it](http://lucky-patcher.netbew.com/)?

To quote from that site linky:

> Lucky Patcher is a great Android tool to bypass premium applications
>   license verification, remove ads, modify Permissions, and more.
>
> To use this application, you need a rooted device.
>
> Know:  Although stable, functioning of Lucky Patcher can't be
>   guaranteed at 100%.  So you are solely responsible of use of this
>   application.  Under no circumstances Netbew be responsible for any
>   problems caused to your device (rebooting loop, unstable system,
>   etc...).

Do not bother wasting time in protecting your app from *that*!

Sorry, if this answer is not what you're looking for, but it is plain and simple, forget anti-cracking - use [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

One is bound to find out how to crack it, don't use LVL, regardless if you claim its *heavily modified*.

And anyway, crackers out there has the time and resource to pirate and crack apps and any anti-cracking **is bound** to be broken in a very short space of time!

Focus on functionality and satisfying your end users!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I think it is huge advantage for crackers to leave an app that insecure that an automatic tool can break it. All what I want to do is actually make it hard enough that a human intervention is needed. That's all. I don't want a simple Joe who has a rooted phone just simply download lucky patcher and break my app. Is that too much to ask for? I don't because if that's the case then android needs a really serious consideration

Comment: *crackers to leave an app that insecure* - let's revisit that statement - it is **you** as programmer that is making it "insecure" :)

Comment: And that's why I am asking here :) so I can make it more secure. I use pro guard and lvl with modifications but I am missing this dalvik modification protection which I asking about in this thread